# Insert div into Horizontal Gallery

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, gallery

I have created an horizontal image gallery with jQuery, based on the work of Edd Turtle: http://www.designedbyaturtle.co.uk/2012/horizontal-scrolling-with-jquery/

I am trying to add a description to the right of the image when the user clicks on it.
So all the images on the right will be replaced by the width of the description.
I think I need to to create a `div`, but with what attributes?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Why do you need an attribute, and on what div? Show some code you have so far?

Comment: Yes, you're right. Thank's.

Answer (score 0):

```css
body { overflow-y: hidden; overflow-x: scroll; }
.gallerie { float:left; width:1000px; position:absolute; }
.photographie { display:block; height:100%; float:left; }

#imageDescription{ display:none; }
.imageLayer{ display:none; position:fixed; background:#FFF; width:5em; }
#imageCheck:checked + .imageLayer, #imageContent:target{ display:block; }
```

```html
<div class="gallerie">
 <a href="#imageDescription"><img class="photographie" src="img/photo/01.jpg"/></a>
 <div class="imageLayer" id="imageDescription"><p>Description of the image</p></div>
 <img class="photographie" src="img/photo/fashion/02.jpg"/>
 <img class="photographie" src="img/photo/fashion/03.jpg"/>
</div>
```